# Ambiguous use of はなして?

Tags: grammar, ambiguity, giving-and-receiving

The younger sister is holding on to the climbing frame, trapped by a wild dog. The older sister is rushing to the rescue:

> 「お姉ちゃん、来ちゃダメだよ、あぶないよぉ」
>   Sister, don't come over here. It's dangerous.
>   私の妹なのよっ、**はなして**っ」
>   You're my little sister, ???

I assume this はなして is from 放す = to release/to let go/to set free. I'm not familiar with the usage of this verb and I was a bit puzzled by the verb ending. I assume the meaning is "I will set you free (rescue you)" and that in ends in て because the sentence is unfinished. Would I be correct that the full sentence is something like 放してもらって下さい?

But I also thought that it might be an instruction to "let go (release grip)" of the climbing frame.

Aside from the fact that letting go of the frame would seem like a poor idea, are both of these interpretations possible? In a situation of panic is this completely unambiguous?

Comment: A guess: She's shouting at the dog?

Comment: @Nothingatall I hadn't thought of that. If I change "You're" to "That's" then that makes a lot of sense. I wonder if that's the only valid interpretation though?

Comment: ^ 引きとめる人に対して、「She's my sister, so let me go (to help her)」って言ってるんじゃないですかね・・・もうちょっと文脈欲しいですね、その場面の絵とか・・・

Comment: @chocolate I thought about "**you're** my sister. Let me help **you**", but then I got confused with causative form and how I would extend はなして to have that meaning. I guess with your translation I don't need to worry about that. It's a simple 'release me' command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the elder sister is yelling this either to the dog:

> 私の妹なのよっ、（妹を）はなしてっ
>   *That* is my sister! Release *her*!

Or to someone else who is trying to stop her from helping her sister:

> 私の妹なのよっ、（私を）はなしてっ
>   *That* is my sister! Release *me*!

Comment: When I read further the second option seems quite convincing. I'd never have thought of it myself though. I was trapped by thinking **You're** my sister. I assume my own suggestions are not valid at all then?

Comment: @user3856370 There is no point in saying "You are my sister!" here :)

Comment: There is certainly no point. But, it would still be a perfectly natural thing to say in English. "You're my sister (so) I want to help you".  Maybe the Japanese are just more economical with words.

Comment: @user3856370 Using so-called "explanatory の" means she's actually trying to convince someone with that fact, so "I wanna/will help you" cannot follow it naturally. But she could have said something like 「私の妹なのよ、自分でなんとかしなさいっ」 to her younger sister :)

Comment: @user3856370 If it was used like that, it would more likely be 「あなたは私の妹なのよ」 so that the "you're" is being stressed.